# Is there any difference between modules & app in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I have installed odoo ver8.0 in my local machine.
I just want to know:

- Is there any difference between modules & apps in odoo. If yes what is it?
- Also i want to know the difference between the links 'Local modules' & 'Apps' in the left menu of odoo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difference between the links 'Local modules' & 'Apps' in the left menu:

The "Apps" are online (it doesn't work to me because I use the OCA version) and the "Local modules" you can install them offline. What I do is install the `disable_openerp_online` module, in order to hide the "Apps" menu, because you can install your own local "Apps" from the "Local modules" menu as well.

The main difference between "Application" and "Module":

> It’s common to hear about Odoo modules and applications. But what
>   exactly is the difference between them? Modules are building blocks of
>   Odoo applications. A module can add or modify Odoo features. It is
>   supported by a directory containing a manifest or descriptor file
>   (named `__openerp__.py`) and the remaining files that implement its
>   features. Sometimes, modules can also be referred to as “add-ons.”
>   Applications are not different from regular modules, but functionally,
>   they provide a central feature, around which other modules add
>   features or options. They provide the core elements for a functional
>   area, such as accounting or HR, around which other modules add
>   features. Because of this, they are highlighted in the Odoo Apps menu.

Answer (score 0):

Modules are individual pieces/directories of code that extend introduce functionality. An app is a collection of modules, usually with a configuration option, that represent the same purpose (for example: Sale or Purchase).
https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/what-is-the-difference-between-an-app-an-addon-and-a-module-56285